# In need of wise peoples advice

Tags: qa-role

I have been a tester for an eCommerce company startup in the travel business,
doing mostly Manuel testing which I found quite boring.
Over the last 8 months (my first job as a QA) and over these 8 month I have been warned once that I need to improve or I will be let go, which I did.

Yesterday I was notified that my performance had gotten very bad again
which surprised me because I was told I was doing good up to a month a go
and wasn't given any feedback to indicate that I am getting worse.

I have my doubts about the validity of that since there was no warning + the company just went into it's second round of fundraising and has been removing a lot of people over past month. 6 out of the 27 workers to be exact.

I have been quite shaken by the situation because I take my job very much to heart and am sorry to say that it hurt my confidence in my testing skills.

So now that I have explained the situation to my question.

Should I try to find another job in QA or call it a day with this profession
or am I overreacting and just taking this failure a bit too much to heart?
I feel like I know the answer to this but I wanted to hear from people with more experience than I do.

Comment: Aside from the words "QA" and "testing", there is nothing about software testing in this question.  You  might be better off asking at  http://workplace.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better servers at https://workplace.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Your doubts are reasonable. It also may be that the requirements have been raised quietly. Never a good sign that.

To know where to go, best ask feedback from the developers/testers you work with. Get a second opinion from someone you trust, who knows you and who has no hidden agenda to be other than honest.

And work on plan B in any case, as it seems your days are numbered. And you as a resource are not sufficiently appreciated to stay.